# Solving $ y' (x) = \dfrac{x^2 + xy + y^2}{x^2} $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ y' (x) = \frac{x^2 + xy + y^2}{x^2} $$

I feel this is actually really simple but it seems I can't get it. The way I am going about this is by trying to integrate by separation of variables, but I am not sure.

Comment: How are you separating the variables?  It’s not obvious in this form.

Comment: The equation is not separable in this form, but it is homogeneous in the sense that $y'=f(x,y)$ where $f(tx,ty)=t^nf(x,y)$ for some $n$.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Let $y = u x $

Then $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = x \dfrac{du}{dx} + u $

Substitute that

$ x u' + u = (x^2 + u x^2 + u^2 x^2 ) / x^2 = 1 + u + u^2 $

Hence,

$ x u' = 1 + u^2 $

Separate the variables and integrate

$ \tan^{-1} u = \ln |x| + C $

Therefore,

$ u = \tan( \ln |x| + C) $

Finally $ y= u x $, so

$ y = x \tan( \ln | x | + C) $

Verification:

$LHS = \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \tan(\ln| x | + C) +  \sec^2 (\ln|x| + C) = \tan(\ln|x| + C) + 1 +  \tan^2(\ln|x| + C)$

$RHS = 1 + \tan(\ln|x| + C) + \tan^2 (\ln|x| + C) $

Answer (score 1):

This equation is (also) a Riccati equation. The constant term on the right side is $1$, so it is convenient to take of all the $y=\frac{u}{v}$ variations the $v=u'$ variant. Then
$$
1-\frac{uu''}{u'^2}=1+\frac{u}{xu'}+\frac{u^2}{x^2u'^2}.
$$
Simplifying and removing common factors leads to
$$
0=x^2u''+xu'+u
$$
which is an Euler-Cauchy equation with characteristic roots $\pm i$. Basis solutions are then $\sin(\ln|x|)$ and $\cos(\ln|x|)$ or in polar/amplitude-phase form
$$
u=A\sin(\ln|x|+C)\implies u'=A\cos(\ln|x|+C)\,\frac1x
\\~\\
y=\frac{u}{u'}=x\tan(\ln|x|+C)
$$